# Updatable Interactive Grid based on multiple tables

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I have 3 tables: Employees, Locations, and EmpLocation

- Employees stores employee data with Employee_ID as primary key,
- Locations stores location data with Location_ID.
- EmpLocation stores Employee_ID and Location_ID. Each Employee can have multiple locations.

I need to create an interactive grid that will display data for all employees, including those that do not have a location assigned to them. 
Then the user needs to have the ability to select a location for those employees that have it as null, and and also to add an additional location to any employee.
I figured what I need is two select lists in  an editable grid. So new row could be added by selecting an employee and corresponding location.

I used the following query:

```
SELECT el.Employee_ID, el.Location_ID
FROM EmpLocations el
```

Then I made each column a select list where the first one pulls data from Employees table:

```
SELECT Employee_FName, Employee_ID FROM Employees
```

and second - from Locations:

```
SELECT Location_Name, Location_ID FROM Locations
```

Everything looks good, but this way I only get employees who has at least one location assigned to them. I need to see all amployees and whether or not they have any locations assigned to them ( each employee can have more than one location assigned).

So I changed the source query for the grid to:

```
SELECT e.Employee_ID, el.Location_ID
FROM Employees e 
LEFT JOIN EmpLocations el ON e.Employee_ID=el.Employee_ID
```

But in this case, will it be possible to make the grid updatable since there are two tables involved?

Answer (score 1):

I'd say yes, but you should get rid of the *automatic row processing* (created by Apex, by default) and write your own PL/SQL code which would do inserting/updating. Something like an instead-of trigger on a view.

Also, for updating purposes (if you'll allow it), include the ROWID pseudocolumn.

Code (untested) would look like this:

```
begin 
  case when :apex$row_status = 'C' then 
         insert into emplocations (employee_id, location_id)
         values (:employee_id, :location_id);
       when :apex$row_status = 'U' then
         update emplocations set
           employee_id = :employee_id,
           location_id = :location_id
           where rowid = :rowid;
       end;
end;
```

Comment: So I would just delete the Process created by APEX? What is `apex$row_status = 'C'`?

Comment: Delete it, or set the condition to "Never" (so that it won't execute). 'C' represents "created", 'U' is "updated", 'D' would be "deleted". More info here: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/HTMDB/concept_sub.htm#CHDBDHIF

Comment: Hi, is this possible in report with form? I have 2 tables joined by id column and need to show them as one report adn the form would do multiple processing. I do not wish to go for views and triggers hence want a solution related to processing. I have this issue on this thread also in case you can take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65791574/oracle-report-with-form-how-to-use-2-tables-for-a-report